# ActivityLibrary for Sharepoint Designer

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to implement an [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629922%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Y915) to create an activity library for Sharepoint Designer, and it gives me this error:

```
Namespace1.CreateTaskInListOnSite' does not contain a definition for 'ListName' and no extension method 'ListName' accepting a ...
```

and the same for `AssignedTo` and 'SiteUrl`.

Shouldn't 'AssignedTo', 'ListName' and 'SiteUrl' be inherited members from SequenceActivity class?

Here is the code which is erred:

```
protected override ActivityExecutionStatus 
Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
{
    try
    {
        SPSite sitecollection = new SPSite(this.SiteUrl); //here
        SPWeb web = sitecollection.OpenWeb();
        SPUser user = web.Users[this.AssignTo[0].ToString()]; // here
        SPList list = web.Lists[this.ListName]; // and here
        SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
        item["Title"] = this.TaskTitle; 
        item["AssignedTo"] = user; 
        item.Update();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MSDN Workflow", ex.ToString());
    }
    return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed; 
}
```

Here is the .actions file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<WorkflowInfo>
<Actions Sequential="then" Parallel="and">
<Action Name="Create Task in List On Site"
 ClassName="Namespace1.CreateTaskInListOnSite"
Assembly="CustomWorkflowActivities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a3170baa21b0a3e9"
AppliesTo="all" Category="Cross Site Actions">
    <RuleDesigner
     Sentence="Create task titled %1 for %2 on site %3 in 
          list %4">
    <FieldBind Field="TaskTitle" DesignerType="TextArea"
       Id="1"/>
    <FieldBind Field="AssignTo" DesignerType="Person"
       Text="this user" Id="2"/>
    <FieldBind Field="SiteUrl" DesignerType="TextArea" Id="3"/>
    <FieldBind Field="ListName" DesignerType="TextArea" Id="4"/>
  </RuleDesigner>
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="TaskTitle" Type="System.String, mscorlib"
      Direction="In" />
    <Parameter Name="AssignTo" Type="System.String, mscorlib"
      Direction="In" />
    <Parameter Name="SiteUrl" Type="System.String, mscorlib"
      Direction="In" />
    <Parameter Name="ListName" Type="System.String, mscorlib"
      Direction="In" />
  </Parameters>
</Action>
```

Comment: Can you also show the .ACTIONS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .ACTIONS file calls the **ClassName** as **MSDN.HowTo.CreateTaskInListOnSite**, where as in your code file you seem to use the namespace **Namespace1**. The two have to match.

So either you change .ACTIONS to this:

```
<Action Name="Create Task in List On Site"
 ClassName="MSDN.HowTo.CreateTaskInListOnSite" .... />
```

or change the namespace definition in your code file to MSDN.HowTo.

The assembly attribute values also have to be correct. You can use the [sn.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to retrieve the public key token for your assembly.

Comment: Updated the namespace in the code and the post, same problem, what about the Assembly attribute?

Comment: You can use the SN tool to get the public key settings for your assembly.

Comment: Even the name of the assembly should point to the assembly generated by the same project?